# Spark saveAsTextFIle goes in endless loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm running spark in stand-alone mode on a single machine. I have a RDD by the name of `productUserVectors`, like this

`[("11342",Map(..)),("21435",Map(..)),...]`

The number of rows in `normalisedVectors` are 8164. I wanted to get all possible pair combinations between the rows of this RDD and compute a score based on the maps in each row. I used `cartesian` to get all possible pairs, and I'm filtering them as shown below

```
scala> val normalisedVectors = productUserVector.map(line=>utilInst.normaliseVector(line)).sortBy(_._1.toInt)
scala> val combinedRDD = normalisedVectors.cartesian(normalisedVectors).filter(line=>line._1._1.toInt > line._2._1.toInt && utilInst.filterStyleAtp(line._1._1,line._2._1))
scala> val scoresRDD = combinedRDD.map(line=>utilInst.getScore(line)).filter(line=>line._3 > 0)
scala> val finalRDD = scoresRDD.map(line=> (line._1,List((line._2,line._3)))).reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
scala> finalRDD.saveAsTextFile(outputPath)
```

I have set driver memory at 8GB and executor memory at 2GB. Here, `utilInst` and it's functions are used to filter pairs from the results of `cartesian` of the original RDD. However, the output shows that it goes into an endless loop as shown by the logs below

```
16/11/17 18:50:14 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.tip.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.id
16/11/17 18:50:14 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.attempt.id
16/11/17 18:50:14 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.is.map is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.ismap
16/11/17 18:50:14 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.partition is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.partition
16/11/17 18:50:14 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.id
16/11/17 18:50:31 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3). 1491 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:50:31 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5). 1491 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:50:31 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5) in 17339 ms on localhost (1/6)
16/11/17 18:50:31 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) in 17346 ms on localhost (2/6)
16/11/17 18:50:31 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1). 1491 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:50:31 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) in 17423 ms on localhost (3/6)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 1491 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2). 1491 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 18092 ms on localhost (4/6)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) in 18063 ms on localhost (5/6)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4). 1491 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4) in 18073 ms on localhost (6/6)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 0 (union at iterateUsers.scala:84) finished in 18.125 s
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: looking for newly runnable stages
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: running: Set()
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: waiting: Set(ResultStage 1)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: failed: Set()
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 1 (ShuffledRDD[11] at reduceByKey at iterateUsers.scala:87), which has no missing parents
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.9 KB, free 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1819.0 B, free 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on 127.0.0.1:60497 (size: 1819.0 B, free: 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 2 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1012
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 6 missing tasks from ResultStage 1 (ShuffledRDD[11] at reduceByKey at iterateUsers.scala:87)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 6 tasks
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 6, localhost, partition 0, ANY, 5126 bytes)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 7, localhost, partition 1, ANY, 5126 bytes)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 8, localhost, partition 2, ANY, 5126 bytes)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 9, localhost, partition 3, ANY, 5126 bytes)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 10, localhost, partition 4, ANY, 5126 bytes)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 11, localhost, partition 5, ANY, 5126 bytes)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 6)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 5.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 11)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 7)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 9)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 8)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 4.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 10)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 6 ms
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 5 ms
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 5 ms
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 5 ms
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 6 ms
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 5 ms
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 9). 1512 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 7). 1512 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 4.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 10). 1512 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 9) in 277 ms on localhost (1/6)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 7) in 283 ms on localhost (2/6)
16/11/17 18:50:32 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 4.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 10) in 279 ms on localhost (3/6)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 8). 1512 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 6). 1512 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 6) in 5120 ms on localhost (4/6)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 8) in 5114 ms on localhost (5/6)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 5.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 11). 1512 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 5.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 11) in 5241 ms on localhost (6/6)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (count at iterateUsers.scala:88) finished in 5.254 s
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: count at iterateUsers.scala:88, took 23.534860 s
8164
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO rdd.UnionRDD: Removing RDD 10 from persistence list
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 10
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: sortBy at iterateUsers.scala:91
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMaster: Size of output statuses for shuffle 0 is 191 bytes
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 1 (sortBy at iterateUsers.scala:91) with 6 output partitions
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 3 (sortBy at iterateUsers.scala:91)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 2)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 3 (MapPartitionsRDD[15] at sortBy at iterateUsers.scala:91), which has no missing parents
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3 stored as values in memory (estimated size 4.4 KB, free 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.5 KB, free 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on 127.0.0.1:60497 (size: 2.5 KB, free: 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 3 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1012
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 6 missing tasks from ResultStage 3 (MapPartitionsRDD[15] at sortBy at iterateUsers.scala:91)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 3.0 with 6 tasks
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 12, localhost, partition 0, ANY, 5210 bytes)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 13, localhost, partition 1, ANY, 5210 bytes)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 14, localhost, partition 2, ANY, 5210 bytes)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 15, localhost, partition 3, ANY, 5210 bytes)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 16, localhost, partition 4, ANY, 5210 bytes)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 17, localhost, partition 5, ANY, 5210 bytes)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 12)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 4.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 16)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 3.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 15)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 13)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 14)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 5.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 17)
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 1 ms
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 1 ms
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:50:37 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
16/11/17 18:50:38 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 5.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 17). 1818 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:50:38 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 4.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 16). 1818 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:50:38 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 3.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 15). 1728 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:50:38 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 12). 1724 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:50:38 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 14). 1727 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:50:38 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 13). 1734 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:50:38 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 5.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 17) in 117 ms on localhost (1/6)
16/11/17 18:50:38 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 4.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 16) in 120 ms on localhost (2/6)
16/11/17 18:50:38 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 3.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 15) in 123 ms on localhost (3/6)
16/11/17 18:50:38 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 12) in 130 ms on localhost (4/6)
16/11/17 18:50:38 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 14) in 128 ms on localhost (5/6)
16/11/17 18:50:38 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 13) in 130 ms on localhost (6/6)
16/11/17 18:50:38 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 3.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/11/17 18:50:38 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 3 (sortBy at iterateUsers.scala:91) finished in 0.133 s
16/11/17 18:50:38 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: sortBy at iterateUsers.scala:91, took 0.154474 s
16/11/17 18:50:38 INFO rdd.ShuffledRDD: Removing RDD 11 from persistence list
16/11/17 18:50:38 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 11
16/11/17 18:50:44 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on 127.0.0.1:60497 in memory (size: 2.5 KB, free: 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:50:44 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on 127.0.0.1:60497 in memory (size: 1819.0 B, free: 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:51:37 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on 127.0.0.1:60497 in memory (size: 3.1 KB, free: 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:52:48 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
16/11/17 18:52:48 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: saveAsTextFile at iterateUsers.scala:99
16/11/17 18:52:48 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 13 (sortBy at iterateUsers.scala:91)
16/11/17 18:52:48 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 22 (map at iterateUsers.scala:98)
16/11/17 18:52:48 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 2 (saveAsTextFile at iterateUsers.scala:99) with 36 output partitions
16/11/17 18:52:48 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 7 (saveAsTextFile at iterateUsers.scala:99)
16/11/17 18:52:48 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 6)
16/11/17 18:52:48 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List(ShuffleMapStage 6)
16/11/17 18:52:48 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ShuffleMapStage 5 (MapPartitionsRDD[13] at sortBy at iterateUsers.scala:91), which has no missing parents
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4 stored as values in memory (estimated size 33.5 MB, free 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.0 MB, free 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_4_piece0 in memory on 127.0.0.1:60497 (size: 4.0 MB, free: 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4_piece1 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.0 MB, free 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_4_piece1 in memory on 127.0.0.1:60497 (size: 4.0 MB, free: 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4_piece2 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.0 MB, free 4.0 GB)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_4_piece2 in memory on 127.0.0.1:60497 (size: 4.0 MB, free: 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4_piece3 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.9 MB, free 4.0 GB)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_4_piece3 in memory on 127.0.0.1:60497 (size: 2.9 MB, free: 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 4 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1012
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 6 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 5 (MapPartitionsRDD[13] at sortBy at iterateUsers.scala:91)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 5.0 with 6 tasks
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 18, localhost, partition 0, ANY, 5207 bytes)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 19, localhost, partition 1, ANY, 5207 bytes)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 20, localhost, partition 2, ANY, 5207 bytes)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 21, localhost, partition 3, ANY, 5207 bytes)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 22, localhost, partition 4, ANY, 5207 bytes)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 23, localhost, partition 5, ANY, 5207 bytes)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 18)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 19)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 20)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 3.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 21)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 4.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 22)
16/11/17 18:52:50 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 5.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 23)
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 1 ms
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 2 ms
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 1 ms
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 20). 1883 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 18). 1883 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 20) in 12006 ms on localhost (1/6)
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 18) in 12011 ms on localhost (2/6)
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 5.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 23). 1883 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 5.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 23) in 12019 ms on localhost (3/6)
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 4.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 22). 1883 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 4.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 22) in 12027 ms on localhost (4/6)
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 3.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 21). 1883 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 3.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 21) in 12044 ms on localhost (5/6)
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 19). 1883 bytes result sent to driver
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 19) in 12059 ms on localhost (6/6)
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 5.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 5 (sortBy at iterateUsers.scala:91) finished in 12.061 s
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: looking for newly runnable stages
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: running: Set()
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: waiting: Set(ShuffleMapStage 6, ResultStage 7)
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: failed: Set()
16/11/17 18:53:02 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ShuffleMapStage 6 (MapPartitionsRDD[22] at map at iterateUsers.scala:98), which has no missing parents
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5 stored as values in memory (estimated size 33.5 MB, free 4.0 GB)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.0 MB, free 4.0 GB)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece0 in memory on 127.0.0.1:60497 (size: 4.0 MB, free: 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5_piece1 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.0 MB, free 4.0 GB)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece1 in memory on 127.0.0.1:60497 (size: 4.0 MB, free: 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5_piece2 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.0 MB, free 4.0 GB)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece2 in memory on 127.0.0.1:60497 (size: 4.0 MB, free: 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5_piece3 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.9 MB, free 4.0 GB)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece3 in memory on 127.0.0.1:60497 (size: 2.9 MB, free: 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 5 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1012
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 36 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 6 (MapPartitionsRDD[22] at map at iterateUsers.scala:98)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 6.0 with 36 tasks
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 24, localhost, partition 0, ANY, 5411 bytes)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 25, localhost, partition 1, ANY, 5420 bytes)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 26, localhost, partition 2, ANY, 5420 bytes)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 27, localhost, partition 3, ANY, 5420 bytes)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 28, localhost, partition 4, ANY, 5420 bytes)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 29, localhost, partition 5, ANY, 5420 bytes)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 6.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 30, localhost, partition 6, ANY, 5420 bytes)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 7.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 31, localhost, partition 7, ANY, 5411 bytes)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 25)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 24)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 4.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 28)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 26)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 3.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 27)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 5.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 29)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 6.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 30)
16/11/17 18:53:05 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 7.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 31)
16/11/17 18:53:13 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_4_piece0 on 127.0.0.1:60497 in memory (size: 4.0 MB, free: 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:53:13 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_4_piece3 on 127.0.0.1:60497 in memory (size: 2.9 MB, free: 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:53:13 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_4_piece2 on 127.0.0.1:60497 in memory (size: 4.0 MB, free: 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:53:13 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_4_piece1 on 127.0.0.1:60497 in memory (size: 4.0 MB, free: 4.1 GB)
16/11/17 18:53:30 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:53:30 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 1 ms
16/11/17 18:53:30 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:53:30 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 1 ms
16/11/17 18:53:30 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:53:30 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 1 ms
16/11/17 18:53:30 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:53:30 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
16/11/17 18:53:30 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:53:30 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
16/11/17 18:53:30 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
16/11/17 18:53:30 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 1 ms
16/11/17 18:53:30 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
```

It gets stuck in the last `storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator` phase endlessly while storing `finalRDD` into a text file. I have no idea as to why it's happening. Any help to resolve this is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the size of normalisedVectors ?

Comment: Logs seem to show normal function. `saveXXX` is materializing the operation, so it's not `save` that's taking long, it's the process before it.  Spark UI for hints on progress and time spent.

Comment: @PascalSoucy, the size of normalisedVectors is 8164.

Comment: The cartesian results in 8164^2 = 66M items to filter, then a few operations on 33M more (getScore, reduceByKey, filter). Could it simply that you haven't waited long enough for the transformations to complete? Like someone said above, it is not the save that takes time, RDD are lazy, so the calculation is done when you materialize with the save operation.